# Print out cursor values

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am modifying a stored procedure which is using a cursor, I want to be able to print out or output the values from the cursor that is inserting into a table but am having a hard time trying to figure out how to do this. I need to check all the values for example that get inserted in the orders table by this stored procedure.

I cant do

```
Print @prodId, @orderQuantity, @orderDate, @orderLocationId, @shipmentId,  @shipmentDate
```

How can I output/print all the values the cursor has in these columns for each record it goes through? An example with how to do this in code would be appreciated.

Comment: you have tagged this with both MySQL and SQL Server?  Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Hi bluefeet, my mistake, I am using MS SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture & store the inserted rows in the correct order by outputting them into a temp table with an identity;

```
create table #inserted(insertorder int identity(0,1), prodId int, orderQuantity int ... <matches inserted row>)

--cursor loop
    insert destination_table(prodId, orderQuantity, ...)
       output inserted.* into #inserted   /*output inserted.* will just select it */
    values @prodId, @orderQuantity ...
--end loop

--inserted rows;
select * from #inserted order by insertorder
```

Answer (score 1):

If using MS SQL Server then you could use RAISERROR. [On this link](http://www.jimmcleod.net/blog/index.php/2010/07/19/print-vs-raiserror/) ypu have a good explanation with samples on how to use them and differences between them. Check out RAISERROR [sintaxis here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/ms178592%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
     PRINT STR(@prodId) + STR(@orderQuantity) + STR(@orderDate) + STR(@orderLocationId) + STR(@shipmentId) + STR(@shipmentDate)
```

If that doesnt work then (for the non int variables) try

```
    CAST(@orderDate as NVARCHAR(MAX))
```

Also look at this article.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Best of Luck

Comment: STR() is not a function in SQL Server

Comment: It *is* a tsql func but it's probably not the right one to use here

Answer (score 0):

When using PRINT, a simple trick instead of STR() which doesn't exist, or `CONVERT(varchar(50), @orderQuantity)`
Which is cumbersome, just use `RTRIM(@orderQuantlty)` for fast implicit conversion from numeric to string.